How can I combine swipe to open drawer and horizontally scrolling widgets?
As soon as I add a drawer to my screen with drawerEnableOpenDragGesture, horizontally swiping inside the drawer drag zone opens the drawer even if directly on a horizontally slidable widget (and does not slide the widget). I want the screen to have priority over opening the drawer (and expected this to be the default behaviour). The minimal code below shows the issue :
MaterialApp(
home:Scaffold(
    drawer: NavigationDrawer(children: [],backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,),
    drawerEnableOpenDragGesture: true,
    drawerEdgeDragWidth: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width/2,
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width*1.5,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(gradient: LinearGradient(begin: Alignment.topRight,
            end: Alignment.bottomLeft, stops: [0.2, 0.6, 0.9], colors:[ 
            Color.fromRGBO(8, 14, 61, 1.0), Color.fromRGBO(19, 31, 131, 1.0),
            Color.fromRGBO(176, 38, 38, 1.0),])),
    ),)
))

I have tried playing with GestureDetector as suggested on some posts but without success so far.
